# Using dynamic programming to find minimal sum in matrix

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming

I need to implement this in my program, let's say we have given matrix with size N*M where N<=100 and M<=15

Now we have to find the minimal sum such that we should pick exactly one element from each column and we cannot pick two elements form different column that are in same row

For example, let N = 3 , M =2
we have the matrix

[3, 0],

[6, 9],

[5, 9],

We can choose 3+9, 6+0, 6+9, 5+0, 5+9, but not 3+0.

I know that i can solve with recursion in N^M time complexity but i need faster solution, please give me some hints.

Comment: Are you sure dynamic programming is the key? Not sure why this should be so.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think dynamic programming is the key because we have to brute force them but carefully

Answer (score 1):

Let's iterate through all rows from 1 to N. Our dynamic programming state will be the pair `(i, j)`, where i is a row number, j - bit mask of already used columns (columns will be zero-based in mask). We will find the values of function `F(i, j)` - minimal sum, that can be achieved using first i rows and taking elements from columns encoded in j. The answer will be the value of `F(N, (1<<M) - 1)`. The recurrence:

```
F(0, 0) = 0
F(0, i) = MAXN, where i > 0        
F(i, j) = min(F(i-1, j), F(i-1, j ^ (1<<k)) + Matrix[i][k+1]), where 0<=k<M, j & (1<<k) != 0
```